# Spring boot test - wait for termination

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application written with Spring boot and I am trying to write some integration tests for it. I want to run my spring boot application and wait until it terminates so I can assert some state.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MyApp.class)
@IntegrationTest("initParams")
public class Test {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    // need to wait until termination
  }
```

Is there any way I can wait for the termination of the Spring app without modifying the application code?

Comment: Have you considered running your app in the test itself?

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: From my answer and your comment, it seem I misunderstood what you were asking. It seems what you want is to be able to launch your application and have it in a running state why you run some integration tests ? However, the confusion comes from the comments in your test: // need to wait until termination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you the test needs the app to terminates, it would be better to actually run the app as part of the test rather than letting the test context starts it for you. I am not sure why you need it and I wouldn't recommend it for all use cases but this could work:

```
public class Test {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    String[] args = new String[]{"initParams"}; // To adapt
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    // whatever
    ctx.close();
    // whatever after the app has terminated.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is a good idea, but here it is: You could perform some asserts in an `@After` and `@AfterClass` methods ?

```
@After
public void afterMethods() {
    //asserts
}

@AfterClass 
public static void afterClass() {
    //asserts
}
```

Comment: The test itself terminates immediately so I don't think it will work :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Yes, the test terminates immediately, isn't the point ? The test loads the Spring Boot settings, you would then normally asserts something, and then the tests ends. With your question, I understood you were looking for a way to test "after" your test.